# Is this mineral wool insulation?

Tags: hvac, insulation

Or is it something else? Old house. This is the air intake to where the gas furnace is. Removed the air filter and saw this.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Could you post a smaller photo so it could be inline?  Its not clear from the photo what it could be.

Answer (score 3):

That is fiberglass Duct Board.   It is used to make air returns and service boxes for your AC and heating system.

Here is a an example: [Duct Board](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-20-in-x-25-in-Duct-board-Return-Air-Box-DRAB20X25/203613226)